# Drag animation (flash? / java?) for C# time slot booking sheet

Tags: c#, java, flash

I have a c# booking application that handles time slot bookings. I am wondering if its worth it to try implement a dragging animation feature whereby the user drags the time slot out to visually indicate the times, as opposed to just having the booking times displayed as text.

```
7.am 8.am 9.am 10.am 11.am 12.am 1.pm 2.pm 3.pm etc
 |========|      |===============| ----> Drag
```

I could possibly do this via flash animation and variable communication but that seems like a lot of work for very little reward. Would java be any simpler?

Any other suggestions?

EDIT: I have a WinForm version, and an ASP.net version for different clients...

Comment: Is this asp.net, on the web?

Comment: Why are you thinking of using Flash or Java in C#? What UI framework are you working in, WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET (MVC)? For all of those you could create a user control that does what you want. If it's web, you can indeed implement some of it (e.g. the dragging and the animation) using Java **Script**.

Comment: This particular app is a standalone winform, however I have an asp.net version that is similar, and would like to use the same animation in both.. USERCONTROLS! What on earth. I have spent so much time with AS3 in Flash and AIR land over the last year I couldn't even think of the glaringly obvious. Thanks CodeCaster for the ice old bucket of water :)